# Is it correct to use alongside in this context? (look at the image)

Tags: word-request

[image]

The image above gives the context in which I'm trying to use **alongside**. It's a web application. I think it would be weird to write "Type the code alongside this text in the app form", so I would just write "Type the code alongside in the app form". Is it correct?

Comment: If you're talking about the word "CODE" that's "above"...

Comment: Are you asking someone to type the long string of numbers that appears in the box that is on the left side of the instructions ?

Comment: Thank you very much guys!!! @ColleenV I think "on the left" fits perfectly, yes I was trying to say that, but I think I didn't make myself clear...now the phrase is this one "Use the code on the left in your mobile app".

Answer (score 2):

If you use

> alongside

the position must be *relative* to something since "*alongside*" is a *relative locator*

> **alongside** the box
>   **alongside** the text

Your instruction

> Alongside in the form

is not correct since it is not relative to an achoring point.

Given the layout of you form, if you want the user to enter a number **in** the box, it would simply be

> Enter the code **in** the box.

Otherwise, *inside* the box, if the number is supposed to be there

> **above** the number
>   **after** the number
>   **below** the number
>   **in front of** the number

are the four possible orientations

> **alongside** the number

has the implied meaning of *before* or *after* since *alongside* is a *horizontal locator* as opposed to *above* or *below*. It also implies that several lines of text can be entered within your box.

If instead the number you are showing is a ***placeholder*** for where the code will be entered, "*in the box*" is appropriate.

But your form only seems to have space *above* or *below* the number already in the box.

Comment: You may want to suggest an alternative wording. How would you instruct someone to enter a number in the box?